# Is it possible to strip out certain logging from nginx error log?

Tags: nginx, error-logging

In my Kubernetes cluster that has nginx and calico pods, there is a lot of logging (at INFO level) in the nginx container coming from the calico pod with regards to connections.

```
2019/01/01 11:43:11 [info] 5130#0: *26124 client closed connection while SSL handshaking, client: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: 0.0.0.0:xxx
```

I would like to know if there's a way to suppress them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to just log information ALERT or NOTICE level and higher by changing your error_log config line to:

error_log logs/error.log alert;

or

error_log logs/error.log notice;